# Please recommend software to draw sequence diagrams

Tags: charts

I have tried Dia, but it does not seem to provide a convenient set. Particularly, I cannot find the self-directed circle in Dia.

I drew the illustration in Word, but it is not very convenient. (The self-directed circle is a circle + an arrow which overlaps the line.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is called a ["sequence diagram"](http://www.google.com/search?q=sequence+diagram+software). I've not seen any that can do the self-directed circle though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [websequencediagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) which is an online sequence charting tool. You can use it for free unless you must use more advanced options. You can choose between few different designs and is very easy to use.

Comment: It does not seem to have self-directed circles.

Comment: There is a `Signal to Self` option which allows you to return the flow from a participant to itself. For example, if you have a participant named `Alice` you can do the following: `Alice -> Alice: Text`